# Switch widget not drawing on Android v5

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a basic switch widget that displays just fine on Android 4.0.3, but doesn't render at all on Android 5.

```
        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/ModeToggle"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textOn="On"
            android:textOff="Off" />
```

Everything inflates successfully, and I even successfully add an event listener to check changed, it just doesn't draw to the screen on v5. On v4.0.3 everything works as expected.

Any ideas what could be going wrong here?

Comment: Try adding `android:showText="true"`

Comment: can you share whole xml which you are inflating ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that I needed to change that activity's theme to `Theme.AppCompat` in order to get it to draw.

Either way, I wouldn't recommend using a switch with text anymore, since Android 5+ makes them really ugly. We decided to use `ToggleButton` instead.